# Do something after two observables are finished

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am doing call to two services:

```js
myfirstService.getCollections().subscribe(collection => myCollection = collection);

mysecondService.getCollectionId().subscribe(id => myId = id);
```

Now I need to get item from collection based on Id, like this

```js
mycollection.find(x => x.id == myId);
```

Of course this should be done after I get collections and id.

Collection and Id is displayed in the UI so I do not want to call one inside another and I don't want to wait till both are done since I need to use collections and id as soon as they are delivered.

Only getting the object should be done after all calls are finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tap` to assign an emitted value to a global variable as soon as you get it. Then execute both Observables simultaneously and wait for them to complete with `forkJoin`.

```js
forkJoin(
  myfirstService.getCollections().pipe(
    tap(collection => myCollection = collection)
  ),
  mysecondService.getCollectionId().pipe(
    tap(id => myId = id)
  )
).subscribe(([collection, id]) => collection.find(x => x.id == id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

Simple Nesting:

```
this.http.get(myfirstService.getCollections()).subscribe(x=> {
    mysecondService.getCollectionId(x.id).subscribe(details=> {
      x.details= details;
    });
});;
```

Using Rxjs **mergeMap**,

```
res= this.http.get(myfirstService.getCollections()).pipe(
  mergeMap(x=> mysecondService.getCollectionId(x.id))
);
```

Comment: though I agree that nesting wouldnt be an issue or forkJoin, "so I do not want to call one inside another"